# Reduce Size py2exe and pyqt

Tags: python, pyqt, py2exe

I just used py2exe to compile my python app that uses pyqt. The size of it is 23MB.
The Pyqt libraries (PyQt4.QtCore.pyd, PyQt4.QtGui.pyd, QtCore4.dll and QtGui4.dll) sum more than 17MB.
Is there a way to use QT with a reduced size?

Thank you!

Comment: It could be that you're having many dependencies, many of which might be unused. Maybe you can try `ldd -u` and it will list the unused dependencies which you could then remove. Just my 2 cents...

Comment: None of the big dependencies can be removed. Just some with only few kbs....

Comment: That's the price you have to pay for the ease of coding in PyQt ;)

Answer (score 0):

PyQt is essentially a wrapper around Qt.
In theory it should be possible to use Qt without PyQt, but you'd have to make the bindings yourself.